# Celery Issues Reading Joblib Saved Files using Numpy Pickle

Tags: python, flask, celery, pickle, joblib

We are experiencing a really weird issue with Celery trying to read model files we're saving with joblib. This is a Flask application using the factory pattern. Here's the overall setup:

`fit_model.py`:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import joblib


class MyClass(Pipeline):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_persist = MyClass(steps=[("step", OneHotEncoder())])
    joblib.dump(to_persist, "dummy.model")
```

`load_model.py`:

```py
import joblib


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("dummy.model", "rb") as f:
        my_object = joblib.load(f)
        assert my_object is not None
```

`tasks.py`:

```py
import joblib

@celery_app.task()
def dummy_task():
    _ = joblib.load("dummy.model")
```

If we run the `lit_model.py` file and then run `load_model.py`, it works perfectly fine. However, when this is run as a Celery task and we try to delay `dummy_task`, we get the following:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lit_service/tasks.py", line 32, in dummy_task
    _ = joblib.load("dummy.model")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1430, in find_class
    return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module 'celery.bin.celery' has no attribute 'MyClass'
```

The Flask Celery worker is setup as so in `application.py`:

```py
celery_app = Celery(
    __name__, broker=settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL, backend=settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL
)

def create_app(**config_overrides):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # start celery
    celery_app.conf.update(app.config)
    celery_app.conf.imports = ["tasks"]
    celery_app.conf.task_routes = {"tasks.*": {"queue": "lit_tasks"}}

    return app
```

And the worker is spawned as a Docker container like so:

```
celery worker -A celery_worker.celery_app --loglevel=INFO --queues lit_tasks
```

Any clues on where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `MyClass` in its own file, such as `my_class.py`, and adding `from my_class import MyClass` to `fit_model.py`.